# reference() function usage in copy.count of resource (Azure RM template)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

In ARM template deployment I need to add firewall exceptions on SQL Server for outbound IP addresses of Azure App Service defined in the same template:

```
{
  "name": "[concat(variables('sqlServerName'),'/azureFireWallRule',copyIndex())]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
  "properties": {
    "startIpAddress": "[split(reference(variables('appServiceRef')).possibleOutboundIpAddresses,',')[copyIndex()]]",
    "endIpAddress": "[split(reference(variables('appServiceRef')).possibleOutboundIpAddresses,',')[copyIndex()]]"
  },
  "copy": {
    "name": "[concat(variables('sqlServerName'),'azureFireWallRule')]",
    "count": "[length(split(reference(variables('appServiceRef')).possibleOutboundIpAddresses,','))]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[variables('sqlServerRef')]",
    "[variables('appServiceRef')]"
  ]
}
```

However usage of reference() function in copy.count is not allowed.

I tried to work around this (not no luck):

- by using condition property
- by having nested deployment resource passing ip count as paramater

Ofc, problem can be solved by 2 sequential deployments. But is there a way to make this happen in terms of single ARM template?

Comment: If you [check the **possibleOutboundIpAddresses** or **outboundIpAddresses** of Azure web app](http://ruslany.net/2015/06/how-to-find-out-outbound-ip-addresses-used-by-azure-web-app/), you can find that normally it contains 4 outbound IP addresses. So you can try to set ``count`` to 4 directly.

Comment: That's not always true. I've had 5-6 possibleOutbounIpAddresses sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood this is impossible.

Reason is that loops are expanded before deployment happens, so no dynamics here is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single template though not a single deployment.  Since possibleOutboundIpAddresses is variable you'd need to deploy the web app, then kick off a nested deployment and output the array.  This nested deployment can be an inline template, it doesn't need to be a separate file and since you're just outputting a value the template can be very simple. (one parameter one output).

That help?

Comment: My intention is to do it in terms of single deployment (and single ARM template). Sorry I was not clear

Comment: You can do it in a single template and a single PUT request from your client, I'm curious about your restriction on the number of deployments?

Comment: I tried that initially and it didn't work for me. Do you have working example?

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/rjmax/ArmExamples/blob/master/NestedTemplateInline.json

Answer (score 0):

```
"providerSpecificDetails": {
      "instanceType": "A2A",
      "fabricObjectId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('gcAppEnv').drDetails.gcAppSourceRG,'/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmNames').vmbuild[copyIndex()].MacName)]",
      "recoveryContainerId": "[variables('targetContainerResourceId')]",
      "recoveryResourceGroupId": "[parameters('gcAppEnv').drDetails.gcAppTargetRGId]",
      "copy": [
        {
          "name": "vmManagedDisks",
          "count": "[add(1, length(parameters('vmList')[copyIndex()].datadisks))]",
          "input": {
            "**diskId**": "[if(equals(copyIndex('vmManagedDisks'), 0), reference(concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',parameters('gcAppEnv').drDetails.gcAppSourceRG, '/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/',variables('vmNames').vmbuild[copyIndex()].MacName), '2019-03-01').storageprofile.osDisk.managedDisk.id, reference(concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',parameters('gcAppEnv').drDetails.gcAppSourceRG, '/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmNames').vmbuild[copyIndex()].MacName), '2019-03-01').storageprofile.dataDisks[sub(copyIndex('vmManagedDisks'),1)].managedDisk.id)]",
            "diskType": "[if(equals(copyIndex('vmManagedDisks'), 0), 'OperatingSystem', 'Data')]",
            "recoveryReplicaDiskAccountType": "[if(equals(copyIndex('vmManagedDisks'), 0), parameters('vmList')[copyIndex()].osDiskType, parameters('vmList')[copyIndex()].datadisks[sub(copyIndex('vmManagedDisks'), 1)].diskType)]",
            "recoveryTargetDiskAccountType": "[if(equals(copyIndex('vmManagedDisks'), 0), parameters('vmList')[copyIndex()].osDiskType, parameters('vmList')[copyIndex()].datadisks[sub(copyIndex('vmManagedDisks'), 1)].diskType)]",
            "primaryStagingAzureStorageAccountId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',parameters('gcAppEnv').drDetails.gcAppSourceRG,'/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountNasaObject').storageAccounts_name)]",
            "diskEncryptionInfo": null,
            "recoveryResourceGroupId": "[parameters('gcAppEnv').drDetails.gcAppTargetRGId]"
          }
        }
      ],
      "selectedRecoveryAzureNetworkId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',parameters('recoveryServicesVaultObject').targetNetworkRG,'/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/',parameters('recoveryServicesVaultObject').targetVNetName)]",
      "recoveryAvailabilityZone": "[if(equals(mod(copyIndex('vmProtectedItemsLoop'),3), 0), '3', if(equals(mod(copyIndex('vmProtectedItemsLoop'), 2), 0),'2','1'))]",
      "recoveryAzureNetworkId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',parameters('recoveryServicesVaultObject').targetNetworkRG,'/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/',parameters('recoveryServicesVaultObject').targetVNetName)]",
      "recoverySubnetName": "[if(equals(variables('vmNames').vmbuild[copyIndex()].VmTier, 'Web'),parameters('gcSubscriptions').DRSubnets.Web, parameters('gcSubscriptions').DRSubnets.App)]"
    }
```

I have tried this code for replicated items. It works.

Comment: Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59184758/edit) to also explain *how* it works, and how it differs from or improves upon the other answers.